# single/multiple value context

Tags: golang

Объясните мне эту магию:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func foo() (string, int) {
    return "Foo", 42
}

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]int)
    m["foo"] = 42
    v := m["foo"] // вот тут мы получаем одно значение 
    fmt.Println(v) // 42
    v, ok := m["foo"] // тут два
    fmt.Println(v, ok) // 42 true
    a := foo() // а так сделать нельзя бросит ошибку: multiple-value foo() in single-value context
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Как заставить мою функцию foo работать как получение значения map по инднексу? Что это вообще за магия?

Answer (score 0):

Всё дело в том, что `map` -- это часть языка. Для пользовательских функций такое недоступно. Если вы хотите пропустить второе значение, то используйте `_`:

```
a, _ := foo()
```

Если же вам нужно API, где можно выбрать сколько значений вам нужно, то делается функция-обёртка. Например:

```
func fooA() (result string) { result, _ = foo(); return }

// ...

a := fooA()
```